# MQTT server to client communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mqtt, ruby-mqtt

I want to communicate between server and client using mosca.At first case i subscribe and publish data from client.And receive that data into server.But i face some problem again i want publish the data from server and receive that data from same client.

Example: From front-end send same data to the server.After receiving those data i want store those data in database.After save the data i want send the some response(data) to the same client using Mosca(in Javascript).

Thanks for giving answer.

Comment: I'm not clear on where you are having the a problem. You want to re-publish the data once it has been saved to the database? What have you already tried?

Comment: so in short you are unable to publish the data in first place, is it so?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to use a MQTT client on browser you should use a option to activate websocket.

Something like this:

```
const mosca = require("./");
const server = new mosca.Server({
  http: {
    port: 3000, //use this port to connect
    bundle: true,
    static: './'
  }
});
```